# list object being passed into ajax has undefined values but list size is correct

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm struggling with altering a table through Ajax. The goal is to sort by column header. Using ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2, I need to know what I am doing wrong. All this code is simplified for testing/Learning;

Model:

```
public class Automobile
{
    public Automobile(){}       }
    public List<Automobile> GetAutos()
    {
       List<Automobile> autos = new List<Automobile> {
            new Automobile{ AutoId = 1,Make="Ford",Model="F150",Year="1986"},
            new Automobile{ AutoId = 2,Make="Chevy",Model="Camaro",Year="1984"},
            new Automobile{ AutoId = 3,Make="Dodge",Model="Durango",Year="2000"},
            new Automobile{ AutoId = 4,Make="Suzuki",Model="Kizashi",Year="2012"},
        };
        return autos; 
    }

    public int AutoId { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }

}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AutoId)
        </th>
        <th>
            <a id="MakeSort" class="text-decoration-none">Make</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tableArea">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AutoId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Make)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the area I am replacing with the sorted table is the TBody 'tableArea'.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Automobile().GetAutos());
    }

    public IActionResult SortMake()
    {
        var autos = new Automobile().GetAutos().OrderByDescending(x => x.Make).ToList();
        return new JsonResult(autos); 
    }
}
```

The Controller action `SortMake` does have the correct list count and values as verified through setting a break point and a watch.

Script:

```
function SortMake(){
    alert("Clicked");
    var direction = "asc";
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SortMake","Home")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'Get',
        data: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#tableArea').empty();
            data.forEach(function (element) {
                $('#tableArea').append(
                    "<tr><td>" + element.AutoId + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + element.Make + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + element.Model + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + element.Year + "</td></tr > ");
            });
            $('#tableArea').show();
        },
        error: function () { alert("Failed");}
    });
}

$('#MakeSort').on("click", SortMake);
```

The data elements in the Succeed function have the correct row count, however all the elements are undefined. Hence I end up with the page as:

```
<tbody id="tableArea">
    <tr>
        <td>undefined</td>
        <td>undefined</td>
        <td>undefined</td>
        <td>undefined</td>
    </tr> ...
```

The Ajax error function never gets hit either.
What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it took some digging, but I added break points to the debugger in chrome at the ajax succeed function, and I added watches to the elements.

It appears the model property names were transformed to lower case. So I changed the ajax data element property names to all lower case. Now I am getting the table data. This teaches me 2 things, 1) Something in ajax or jquery ToLowered() my model property names, so I need to watch that next time. And 2) it taught me how to use the browser debugger to dig deeper.

If anyone was trying to work on this for me,, Thank you very much.

Now I need to try to persist the sort order to toggle the direction.